# Dimensions of a rectangle containing a rotated rectangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rectangles

Given sides **a**, **b**, and an arbitrary rotation Θ (0 - 360 degrees) around the centerpoint of the rectangle, how would I calculate sides **A** and **B** of a containing rectangle?

[image: Illustration of rectangles in question]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

B = $a*sin(90-\theta)+b*sin(\theta)$

A = $b*sin(90-\theta)+a*sin(\theta)$

(Assuming the image shows minor clockwise rotation)

when $\theta=0\  $ $B=a\  $   $A=b\  $ (matching the image)

Comment: how did you arrive to this result? I have no idea where to start

Comment: Look at the triangles surrounding the inner rectangle.

Comment: Oh! Got it, thanks!

Comment: In practice, I need to use the absolute values of each component (i.e. A = Abs(b * sin(90-θ)) + Abs(a * sin(θ)) ) or else the results are incorrect when using angles over 90 degrees. However, this helped a lot, and I really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: absolutely brilliant